# how to install themes/icons themes with lxappearance

Tags: gtk, openbox, theme, icons

In lxappearance there is a git "+ install" button but it only accepts .tar.gz files.  When downloading a theme/icon theme, the file is a .tar.xz, and when I try to turn the .tar.xz into a .tar.gz it says `(lxappearance:1975): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:45:39.810: Source ID 1301 was not found when attempting to remove it`. How am I supposed to install a theme/icon theme? I am using openbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually extract the archive to your `~/.icons` folder.

Make sure to not add an additional folder depth i.e. inside the `.icons` folder should be folder with the icon theme name and this folder should contain all the icon theme stuff.

`lxappearance` should now show the icon theme in the list without importing it.

Comment: thanks to respond to this but since then I switched to arch and a tilling windows manager and I don't use lxappearance anymore, I will accept your answer and I wish it's gonna help other but I did not used it

Comment: This is actually what i had to do on Arch with the tiling i3. Thanks for accepting!